# Ubuntu Server stuck searching 2 minutes on disconnected network adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ssh, ethernet

Edit3: yeah I don’t have an interface folder in my network either weird
Edit2: potential fix seems to be amending
The Ethernet in /etc/network/interfaces from auto -name- to allow-hotplug
I have yet to learn how to edit a file, will report back. Hypothesis is a dhcp server request is sent but no reply as there is no Ethernet cable.
Edit: was asked for a concatenation of my /etc/netplan/*.yaml files, didn’t have perms for 1 of the files, so I raised to sudo: files return. Forgive my formatting

```
network: 
  version 2:
  wifis: 
    WiFirouter:
    Access-points:
       Mywifi:
         Password: mypassword
       dhcp4: true 
Network:
  Ethernets:
     enp3s0
       Dhcp4: true
 Version 2:
```

To me it looks like the Ethernet is listening on a dhcp server for whatever reason.
I cannot get iw dev to work, had to sudo apt install, but I don’t know installing yet,

```
 Interface wixb07fb9438ad4 (this is the one I already want to use)
   ifindex 3
wdev 0x1
addr bo: ——
ssid wifiname type —-
channel 5 (2432 MHz), width: 20 MHZ, center1: 2432 MHz txpower 18.00 dBm multicast TXQ:
```

The boot message causing hang time is

```
[*****] A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured (52s / no limit)
```

Basically I installed Ubuntu Jellyfish, on an old desktop which had an Ethernet port (unused) and a usb nfic wireless adapter (in use) and I must have messed up the network config on install (first time, learning Linux)

On server boot, it hangs while waiting to connect 0sec/insefinitely
But at around 2:30 it swaps to the secondary network adapter, my usb.

I found the networkctl command, and I notice that my Ethernet is yellow “configuring”

I think the correct command is somewhere in netplan

But I’m trying to either disable the Ethernet port or set it as secondary

Additionally I also have to setup SSH for the secondary adapter because im pretty sure it defaulted to the Ethernet connection.

I’m just a young grasshopper, learning some commands such as whatis man and flagging help for everything else.

speak to me as a plebian who knows nothing about gnu/linux

Comment: Let's start by troubleshooting your netplan configuration. Please edit your question to add the results of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `iw dev` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have edited the main post to provide the concatenation of my yaml file, but the iw dev just shows the current connection, I already have access on my second wireless interface.

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you amend the netplan file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

Change it to read:

```
network: 
  version 2:
  renderer: networkd
  wifis: 
    wlxb07fb9438ad4:
      access-points:
        “Mywifi”:
          password: “mypassword”
      dhcp4: true 
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

If, in fact, the ethernet is not being used at all, change the ethernet stanza to:

```
network:
      ethernets:
         enp3s0
           dhcp4: false
           optional: true
```

Please note that netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc. Please proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot and test.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are running in a VM, and sometimes I have one or the other interface "unplugged" for various reasons, I ended up setting both interfaces to "optional: true" and this worked for me instead.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
```